# Google oauth using Nest-js graphql code first approach with passport package and React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, nestjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to learn graphql using Nest Js. For this I am using react native as my front-end. I have covered some basic functionalities like connecting with database, writing user resolver and services etc at the server side. Now I am trying to implement authentication to my app. I have implemented credential signin and signup part using jwt strategy, local strategy, jwt-auth guard and gql-auth guard and it's working fine. Now I am trying to implement google oauth for which I have added some code as shown below

**google.strategy.ts**

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Profile } from 'passport';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get('GOOGLE_ID'),
      clientSecret: configService.get('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    console.log('profile', profile);
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      name: name.givenName + ' ' + name.familyName,
      picture: photos[0].value,
      accessToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

**google-auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('google') {}
```

and some dummy resolver just for testing purpose

**auth.resolver.ts**

```
@Mutation(() => Boolean)
  @UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
  async googleLogin(): Promise<boolean> {
    return true;
  }
```

I am not getting why is this not working. Am I missing expo-auth-session package in my front-end? Can this be done without using expo-auth-session? or is these anything else I am missing?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.